# Retrieving Action Signature Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have an action method that looks like this:

```
    [return: Safe]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get([Safe] SomeData data)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

The [Safe] attribute is a custom attribute I made.  I want to create an ActionFilter that locates the [Safe] attribute either on the parameters or on the return type.  I already have this working for the parameters within the OnActionExecuting override, because I can access my [Safe] attribute like this:

```
//actionContext is of type HttpActionContext and is a supplied parameter.
foreach (var parm in actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding.ParameterBindings)
{
    var safeAtts = parm.Descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SafeAttribute>().ToArray();
}
```

But how do I retrieve the [Safe] attribute that was placed onto the return type?

There might be something to explore by taking this approach:

```
ModelMetadataProvider meta = actionContext.GetMetadataProvider();
```

But if this does work, it is unclear how to make it work with the `ModelMetadataProvider`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Try casting the [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.actiondescriptor.aspx) property from the [`HttpActionContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.aspx) to [`ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.reflectedhttpactiondescriptor.aspx) first.
Then use the [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.reflectedhttpactiondescriptor.methodinfo.aspx) property to retrieve your custom attribute via its [`ReturnTypeCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntypecustomattributes.aspx) property.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  ...
  var reflectedActionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
  if (reflectedActionDescriptor != null)
  {
    // get the custom attributes applied to the action return value
    var attrs = reflectedActionDescriptor
                  .MethodInfo
                  .ReturnTypeCustomAttributes
                  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (SafeAttribute), false)
                  .OfType<SafeAttribute>()
                  .ToArray();
  }
  ...
}
```

---

### Update: Tracing Enabled

It seems the concrete type for [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.actiondescriptor.aspx) depends on whether or not the [Global Web API Services](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#services) contains an instance of [`ITraceWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.tracing.itracewriter.aspx) (see: [Tracing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)).

By default, the [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.actiondescriptor.aspx) will be of type [`ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.reflectedhttpactiondescriptor.aspx). But when tracing is enabled — by calling the `config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing()`— the [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.actiondescriptor.aspx) will be wrapped inside an [`HttpActionDescriptorTracer`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Tracing/Tracers/HttpActionDescriptorTracer.cs) type instead

To workaround the issue we'll need to check whether or not the [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.actiondescriptor.aspx) implements an [`IDecorator<HttpActionDescriptor>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn202017.aspx) interface:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  ...
  ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor reflectedActionDescriptor;
  
  // Check whether the ActionDescriptor is wrapped in a decorator or not.
  var wrapper = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as IDecorator<HttpActionDescriptor>;
  if (wrapper != null)
  {
    reflectedActionDescriptor = wrapper.Inner as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
  }
  else
  {
    reflectedActionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
  }
  
  if (reflectedActionDescriptor != null)
  {
    // get the custom attributes applied to the action return value
    var attrs = reflectedActionDescriptor
                  .MethodInfo
                  .ReturnTypeCustomAttributes
                  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (SafeAttribute), false)
                  .OfType<SafeAttribute>()
                  .ToArray();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: No good.  The ActionDescriptor won't cast to a ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.  It is actually of type HttpActionDescriptorTracer, which I think is internal.

Comment: @Brent sorry for the late reply. I think I've found the problem. It's related to tracing. Please see my updated answer.